# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'html')

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-jest

I am trying to introduce Jest to my current project.

However, during the initial setup, I encountered this error and it is not running properly.

How can I solve this?

I am currently using vue2 from vue-cli.

```
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'html')

      at new JSDOMEnvironment (node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:72:44)
      at async TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:317:13)
      at async runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:407:19)
      at async _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:338:7)
      at async runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:190:3)
```

This is my test code.

```
import SettlementProcessing from "@/views/calculate/SettlementProcessing.vue";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
describe("Settlement Component", () => {
  let vuetify;
  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify();
  });
  it("정산 처리 타이틀이 나와야 한다.", () => {
    const sc = shallowMount(SettlementProcessing, { vuetify });
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Here is my package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.21",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.0",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
  }
```

Here is my jest.config.json.

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "json",
    "vue",
  ],
  transform: {
    "^[^.]+.vue$": "vue-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)",
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/", "/dist/"],
  collectCoverage: false,
  collectCoverageFrom: ["**/*.{js,vue}", "!**/node_modules/**"],
};
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: Can you try to add the following property in your jest.config.json file: ```testEnvironment: 'jsdom'```

Answer (score 55):

I had the same issue when updating my react app to jest 28. The issue was the missing jest-environment-jsdom package which was not yet necessary in jest 27.

See https://jestjs.io/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28

Comment: on your terminal run: yarn add --dev jest-environment-jsdom

Comment: the link no longer works, maybe you can update the link to here? https://jest-archive-august-2023.netlify.app/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28/#jsdom

Answer (score 9):

It was fixed for me by adding `jest-environment-jsdom`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `localVue` instance and use `Vuetify` on it. This can be achieved either in a `tests/setup.js` file (which runs for all jest tests) or separately in each unit test that uses Vuetify.

Sample code without `setup.js` (if you use `setup.js`, the code will be slightly different, you can check the documentation below)

```js
import SettlementProcessing from "@/views/calculate/SettlementProcessing.vue";
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuetify)

describe("Settlement Component", () => {
  it("정산 처리 타이틀이 나와야 한다.", () => {
    const sc = shallowMount(SettlementProcessing, { localVue } );
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The documentation is here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing/#bootstrapping-vuetify

Comment: I tried the same with the method you pointed out, but I get the same error.

I don't know why the error occurs..

Comment: Oh, in that case please ignore my answer. It was worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed for me by changing the file ending of the test from tsx to ts